# Avro serialization exception - java.time.Instant cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I want to send a Kafka message with a payload of a class that extends *SpecificRecordBase*; it is a class that has been generated with the help of a maven plugin.

One of the fields of my schema has a type of timestamp-millis, which corresponds to the java.time.Instant in the generated class.

The field is defined as follows:

```
{"name": "processingTime", "type": {
   "type": "long",
   "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
   }
},
```

When I create an instance of this class and set the processing time,

```java
setProcessingTime(RandomDate.randomInstant())
```

everything is ok, but when I run the program and try sending it to Kafka, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class poc.avroGenerated.AvroMeasurement to class poc.avroSerde.AvroSerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.Instant cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.time.Instant and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Here's my custom serializer class:

```java
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {

    byte[] result = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(data.getSchema());
        datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);
        binaryEncoder.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SpecificDatumWriter` instead of `GenericDatumWriter`.

Drop in that one change, and your custom serializer looks fine!

This is frequently a point of confusion.  In the Java implementation, "generic" datum do not take into account any customizations that were built into a specific record, including logical type conversions.

Comment: It works! A few more questions: It works both for DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = ... and DatumWriter<SpecificRecord> datumWriter = .... Why is it so? Does an implicit casting take place somewhere? Does it impact the way data gets serialized, and thus influences later deserialization processes?

Comment: It should also work for `DatumWriter<Object>` and `DatumWriter<T>`!  As long as the method compiles, it's all the same implementation in the end.

(The template type for DatumWriter is erased after compilation any way -- the important thing was to change the implementing class.)

Comment: "This is frequently a point of confusion. In the Java implementation, "generic" datum do not take into account any customizations that were built into a specific record, including logical type conversions.": thank you @RyanSkraba. That explains a lot of things... especially why I got lots of `ClassCastException`...

Comment: @RyanSkraba I get the same `ClassCastException` when using `com.linkedin.avro.fastserde.FastSpecificDatumWriter` (and vis versa when using `com.linkedin.avro.fastserde.FastSpecificDatumReader`). Is it a known problem? Does it have a solution?